# Centos/RH6: iptables rule to allow all ports to specific IP

Tags: iptables, centos6

How do I open all ports to a specific source (inbound) IP address?

I am trying to allow health checking from a monitoring service. When IPtables is off the monitoring server is able to run it's checks, however it fails when IPtables is up.

I've tried creating specific rules for each service/port the monitoring server supposedly uses (ICMP, SNMP, etc), however with these in place the monitoring services are still failing to communicate with the server. This tells me the monitoring service is probably trying to run something outside the documented services/ports, so I'd like to allow it to hit any port/service on the target host.

This is what I have so far, but it's failed (based on this post http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=338297):

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution works for whatever reason. Perhaps I had a typo elsewhere that I couldn't see...or trying to designate protocols explicitly was breaking something.

-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Could be that the monitoring server first does a ping and when that fails (since icmp isn't open in the first post) it doesn't try anything else.
This last command allows any ipv4 traffic from 192.168.1.1, be that tcp, udp, icmp or anything else as long as it has that ip.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried to open JUST port 7 for ICMP echo, but perhaps it was trying to use a different port. Trying to create two rules to cover UDP and TCP just seemed stupid for a trusted monitoring appliance, hence me just opening all the ports to that particular IP. Vuola.

Hopefully others can benefit. I couldn't find an example anywhere of opening all ports to a particular IP/Subnet.

Comment: I guess iptables expects a set of ports attached to a rule with protocol (tcp or udp), probably you would need "any" like in Cisco (in whatever syntax iptables accepts an any) to be explicitly supplied to allow the traffic. And your rule is actually a "permit ip" type of rule, aka L3 or protocol agnostic. In order to open icmp-echo you should have used `-p icmp --icmp-type echo` like here https://serverfault.com/questions/495054/restricting-icmp-using-iptables